# Why doesn't the 1D series support RC units?

Tags: canon, remote, wireless-triggers

Is there a official or known reason why the 1D series doesn't support RC units (infrared remotes such as the Canon RC-6) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because most users of the 1-series cameras from Canon don't expect to use their 1-series camera in situations that lend themselves to infrared remotes. Most pros who desire to release the shutter of their camera via a wireless remote use radio triggers that are much more reliable and configurable in environments that are usually rich with sources that would interfere with the operation of a very limited range IR remote.

Comment: And for studio work, remote firing from any flash is also a possibility since Canon's speedlite system allows for remote firing of the camera via either the optical sync or radio sync systems.